# Singleton 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor' isn't currently in creation

Tags: java, spring

As of now I am using spring version 3.1.1.RELEASE and sometimes while starting the server or during running of multiple testcases I am getting the error.

I want to check is it the behaviour of spring or is it because of wrong way of configuring the beans

````
11:58:41,727 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./gwwar: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./gwwar: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public com.xyz.rest.resteasy.SpringApplication()
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public com.xys.rest.resteasy.SpringApplication()
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:162)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2298)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:340)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:253)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:250)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:565)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:536)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:578)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor' isn't currently in creation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.afterSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:239)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at com.xys.util.CommonsUtil.getApplicationContext(CommonsUtil.java:1276)
    at com.xys.rest.resteasy.XYZService.<init>(SpringPaymentService.java:98)
    at com.xys.rest.resteasy.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:150)
    ... 28 more

11:58:41,734 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "gwwar.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./gwwar" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public com.xys.rest.resteasy.SpringApplication()
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public com.xys.rest.resteasy.SpringApplication()
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor' isn't currently in creation"}}```
````

Comment: ```[org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Bean 'proxyAsyncConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$91c2750] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)```
I am seeing this warning as well

Comment: That is a warning which you can ignore. The stacktrace you addedis a partial one, please post the full stacktrace. Also the fact that you have a `CommonsUtil` with a `getApplicationContext` is a bit worrying you shouldn't have something like that in a spring application.

Comment: One more observation is this is happening when I am adding jacocoagent for generating the test report/end to end coverage report during integration testing.
https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/

Comment: Looks like you are doing things in a wrong way (imho). Are you refreshing the context or just creating it?

Comment: I am just creating the context. I am using both xml and java way to load beans. Is that affecting? This is happening during the application startup. If I remove jacoco agent things work but if I add jacoco agent this issue is coming.

Comment: The issue is resolved. There was a bug 3.1.1.RELEASE spring version and it got fixed in 3.2.9.RELEASE. 
Bug info : https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8824?redirect=false